# How to access localhost using mobile browser?

Tags: php, wamp

Hello I am using **WAMP server** in my pc, I am developing website and the project is stored in **C:\wamp\www\myproject folder**. I connected my **phone** through **WIFI** and from the phone browser I am trying to access local host by entering my PC **IP Address** 192.23.141.30 but it does not displaying my project website.

*Plese give me any method you know to access localhost if you know.*
Thank's in advance...

Comment: 192.23.141.30/myproject

Comment: @MikeMiller I tried that but still it's not accessing ... please tell me another method you know...

Answer (score 0):

Left click the WAMP icon in your taskbar and click 'Put Online'. This should allow access to everyone and not just localhost. Then enter the link into your mobile as `192.23.141.30/myproject`.

Comment: Actually my WAMP is online I checked once again and started it again as your comment but still this does not resolve the problem...

Comment: It's a tad strange that your internal IP is 192.23.x.x and not 192.168.x.x. Leads me to think you might be in an office setting or where you may not have access to settings that may be preventing you from reaching WAMP from your phone. What's your phone's IP?

Comment: but I think it does matter which is my IP is. Because it is randomly changes

Comment: What is the IP your phone is getting from the WiFi connection?

Comment: I think phones IP is not necessary for connection

Comment: Your phone and your PC might be on different subnets or VLANs and may not be able to communicate with each other because of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84730/discussion-between-abhijit-kumbhar-and-gh0st).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could access your localhost with your LAN ip. Make sure that your firewall don't block the access.

Alternative is to simulate your phone on your pc. See for example: http://www.opera.com/nl/developer/mobile-emulator

Comment: My firewall does not give me any error of blocking, If you know how do I find if firewall blocking the access then please tell me...